# WillPopScope navigate page change Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Is it possible to change Navigate page when press device back button?

I tried but not working.

```
return WillPopScope(
  onWillPop: ()=> Navigator.of(context)
      .pushNamedAndRemoveUntil('/home', (Route<dynamic> route) => false),
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes is possible, only add a async and return false

```
onWillPop: () async {
    Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(context, '/home', (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
    return false;
  }
```

I'll that this help